# calloc: 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

The following message gets generated after running my program under valgrind:

```
4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 11
==21938==    at 0x4C2DD10: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:623)
==21938==    by 0x401636: main (syntax.c:187)
```

That's the line of code where the leak was detected:

```
char *word = calloc(4, sizeof(char));   //syntax.c:187
```

I'm not understanding what's wrong with the code above. Why is valgrind generating an error?

Comment: Because you never `free`d it.

Comment: Note that `sizeof(char)` always is `1`

Comment: @melpomene That's definitely what caused the error generation. I updated my code, and the error have disappeared. thanks.