# I don't understand why I'm definitely losing blocks of memory

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

As a project I'm creating a student database. However according to valgrind there's memory leak in my program and I don't know why.
I can't really say much more: I don't understand why memory is being definitely lost.

Student structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char student_number[7];
    char *first_name;
    char *last_name;
    int round_points[6];
} Student;
```

Disclaimer: I'm using the gcc option `-std=c99`, so I had to implement my own `strdup()`.

Important pieces of code:

```
char *copy_string(const char *string) {
    int len = strlen(string);
    char *copy = calloc(len + 1, sizeof(char));
    if (copy == NULL)
        return NULL;
    strcpy(copy, string);
    /* copy[len] = '\0'; */
    return copy;
}

char **parse_one_line_params(const char *one_line, int param_count) {
    char *copy = copy_string(one_line);
    if (copy == NULL)
        return NULL;
    //copy_start is used to free the copy string in the end
    char *copy_start = copy;
    //It is assumed that one_line is of the form COMMAND|SPACE|ARGUMENTS
    //Move pointer to the first important character
    copy += 2;
    const char *separator = " ";
    char **content = malloc(sizeof(char *) * param_count);
    if (content == NULL)
        return NULL;
    int occurrences = 0;
    char *delimiter_start;
    while ((delimiter_start = strstr(copy, separator)) != NULL) {
        delimiter_start[0] = '\0';
        char *sub_string = copy_string(copy);
        if (sub_string == NULL)
            return NULL;
        if (sub_string[0] != '\0') {
            content[occurrences] = sub_string;
        }
        //Since separator is of the length of one
        copy = delimiter_start + 1;
        occurrences++;
    }
    //param n - 1 will be assigned from the last portion of copy
    if (occurrences != param_count - 1)
        return NULL;
    int last_len = strlen(copy);
    if (last_len > 0 && copy[last_len - 1] == '\n')
        copy[last_len - 1] = '\0';
    content[occurrences] = copy_string(copy);
    free(copy_start);
    return content;
}

char **deliver_payload(const char *one_line, int param_count) {
    if (one_line[1] != ' ') {
        printf("Command was longer than one character.\nPlease see manual for instructions\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    char **payload = parse_one_line_params(one_line, param_count);
    if (payload == NULL) {
        printf("Invalid arguments for given command\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    return payload;
}
```

The error in question is:
(records 1 to 5 are the same as below)

```
==15== 32 bytes in 4 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 7
==15==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==15==    by 0x400ECA: copy_string (projekti.c:80)
==15==    by 0x400F81: parse_one_line_params (projekti.c:106)
==15==    by 0x4010B6: deliver_payload (projekti.c:133)
==15==    by 0x4019A2: main (projekti.c:301)
```

Line 301 is just:

```
char **payload = deliver_payload(one_line, 3);
```

Edited version of the code:

```
char **parse_one_line_params(const char *one_line, int param_count) {
    char *copy = copy_string(one_line);
    if (copy == NULL)
        return NULL;
    //copy_start is used to free the copy string in the end
    char *copy_start = copy;
    //It is assumed that one_line is of the form COMMAND SPACE ARGUMENTS
    //Move pointer to the first important character
    copy += 2;
    const char *separator = " ";
    char **content = malloc(sizeof(char *) * param_count);
    if (content == NULL) {
        free(copy_start);
        return NULL;
    }
    int occurrences = 0;
    char *delimiter_start;
    while ((delimiter_start = strstr(copy, separator)) != NULL) {
        delimiter_start[0] = '\0';
        char *sub_string = copy_string(copy);
        if (sub_string == NULL) {
            for (int i = 0; i < occurrences; i++) {
                free(content[i]);
            }
            free(copy_start);
            return NULL;
        }
        if (sub_string[0] != '\0') {
            int sub_len = strlen(sub_string);
            content[occurrences] = calloc(sub_len + 1, sizeof(char));
            strncpy(content[occurrences], sub_string, sub_len);
            free(sub_string);
        }
        //Since separator is of the length of one
        copy = delimiter_start + 1;
        occurrences++;
    }
    //param n - 1 will be assigned from the last portion of copy
     if (occurrences != param_count - 1) {
        printf("Too few parameters\nAborting\n");
        if (occurrences > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < occurrences; i++) {
                free(content[i]);
            }
        }
        free(content);
        return NULL;
    }
    int last_len = strlen(copy);
    if (last_len > 0 && copy[last_len - 1] == '\n')
        copy[last_len - 1] = '\0';
    content[occurrences] = calloc(last_len + 1, sizeof(char));
    strncpy(content[occurrences], copy, last_len);
    /* content[occurrences] = copy_string(copy); */
    free(copy_start);
    return content;
}
```

Edit valgrind:
(in the full output the problematic lines are 140 and 118 i.e. the callocs)

```
==15== 13 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 7
==15==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==15==    by 0x4011B0: parse_one_line_params (projekti.c:140)
==15==    by 0x401236: deliver_payload (projekti.c:153)
==15==    by 0x401B22: main (projekti.c:321)
==15== 
==15== 27 bytes in 6 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 7
==15==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==15==    by 0x401075: parse_one_line_params (projekti.c:118)
==15==    by 0x401236: deliver_payload (projekti.c:153)
==15==    by 0x401BBE: main (projekti.c:337)
```

Last edit: I solved this particular problem: I forgot to free the parameter list in the main function so in the end, I was barking the wrong tree.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43967592/calloc-4-bytes-in-1-blocks-are-definitely-lost#comment74965161_43967592

Comment: I believe it's the `sub_string` that you don't always free.

Comment: @GSerg How would I then assign the sub_string to say content[0]? By memcpy?

Comment: @GSerg Please see edit. I now allocate memory for each element in content, copy with strncpy, free the sub_string and still get essentially the same problem. Why is this?

Comment: `deliver_payload` returns an allocated array of pointers to allocated character strings, making it the responsibility of its caller  (`main`) to free this storage. Since you don't show `main`, it's hard to say whether it's attempt to free this memory is buggy or non-existent, but the fact that you don't consider its code "important" is suggestive.

Comment: @rici You had a right hunch, in the end the fault was in the main function. I forgot to free the parameter list after use.

Comment: Sorry, what's the reason to say: _I'm using the gcc option `-std=c99`, so I had to implement my own `strdup()`._  There's no need to do that, I've just tried with clang and no message output from the compiler.  You don't need to reimplement `strdup()` and worse, never use `calloc()` if you are going to intialize the string yourself.  `calloc()` initializes the space to zeros, so its initialization is redundant.

Comment: @LuisColorado The reason for _I'm using the gcc option_ `-std=c99`,_ so I had to implement my own_ `strdup()` is because instructions I was given specified gcc option of `-std=c99`

Comment: @SampoPaukkonen, that doen't imply you have to implement `strdup()`, you can use the stdlib `strdup()` implementation in c99.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the fault was in main function where I forgot to free the newly created parameter list. Thanks for @GSerg and @datenwolf for pointing out other mistakes in my code.

Answer (score 5):

You have a memory leak here

> ```
> char **parse_one_line_params(const char *one_line, int param_count){
>     char *copy = copy_string(one_line);
>     if (copy == NULL)
>         return NULL;
>
>     /* ... */
>
>     char **content = malloc(sizeof(char *) * param_count);
>     if (content == NULL)
>         return NULL;
> ```

If `malloc` returns NULL for `content`, you return from the function without freeing the memory of `copy`. `malloc` is extremely unlikely to fail, but if the rest of your code is written in the same pattern, then this is where the leaks come from.

It doesn't suffice to "balance" each `malloc`/`strdup`/`calloc` with **a** `free`. You must keep track of where you allocate memory and free it in case the last pointer you have access to it goes out of scope *or is overwritten* (thanks @Ctx).

Comment: There are multiple `return NULL` there, each one except the first has this property, and some don't even depend on malloc returning null.

Comment: Goes out of scope _or_ is overwritten

Comment: @datenwolf Please see edit. I know free the sub_string, allocate memory with calloc for each of the elements in content and copy the sub_string with strncpy. Yet I now get a modified version of the original valgrind error. Why is this?